# How to increase the value of a unix timestamp stored in a variable by X hours?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have a php function that creates a unix timestamp and stores it in a variable. Let's call that variable $timestamp. I'm looking for a function that will allow return two new variables that are a each a different number of hours later than the original timestamp. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This will return a date 3 and 7 days after the supplied date as a unix timestamp. You can edit the math to get the times you need.

```
$timestamp = date('U');
var_dump(get_more_dates($timestamp));

function get_more_dates($timestamp){

    // 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 3 days
    $new_date_1 = (60*60*24*3)+timestamp;
    $new_date_2 = (60*60*24*7)+timestamp;

    return array( $new_date_1, $new_date_1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
date( "Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime( $timestamp ) + $hours * 3600 );
```

`strtotime` to convert the timestamp string to timestamp value;
then adding the `no. of seconds` (hours*36*36); then converting back to the timestamp format using `date()`

So, you can simply add this code to a function, and give any desired values of `$hours`; to get the-

> different number of hours later than the original timestamp